# objCmd doesn't work in the function, the page goes to the internal server error page

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I have the following function:

```
sub SaveChanges()
dim objParam

objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Site_Items_prices.strikethroughPrice, SitePriceID, BasePrices.Price AS MinPrice FROM Site_Items_Prices, Items, Products, BasePrices, BasePriceGroups, Sites WHERE Site_Items_Prices.PriceID = Items.PriceID AND Items.ProductID = Products.ProductID AND BasePrices.PriceID = Items.PriceID AND BasePriceGroups.GroupID = BasePrices.GroupID AND Sites.BasePriceGroup = BasePriceGroups.GroupID AND Site_Items_Prices.ItemID = " & Clng(request.QueryString("id")) & " AND SiteID = " & Clng(intSite)
set objRS1 = objCmd.Execute
strError = ""

do until objRS1.eof
    if CDbl(request.form("price" & objRS1("SitePriceID"))) < CDbl(objRS1("MinPrice")) AND intSite <> 0 then
        strError = "One or more of your prices were not updated because the price you entered was below the minimum price"
    else
        objCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Site_Items_Prices SET Price = ?, strikethroughPrice = ? WHERE SitePriceID = " & objRS1("SitePriceID")
        set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("Price", 14, 1, , request.form("price" & objRS1("SitePriceID")))
        set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("strikethroughPrice", 14, 1, , request.form("strikeprice" & objRS1("SitePriceID")))
        objParam.Precision = 7
        objParam.NumericScale = 2
        objCmd.Parameters.Append( objParam )

        call objCmd.Execute
        objCmd.Parameters.Delete(0)

    end if
    objRS1.movenext
loop
objRS1.close
if strError = "" then strError = "Changes saved successfully" else 

response.Redirect("site_prices.asp?err=1&id=" & request.QueryString("id"))
end sub
```

When I call the objCmd.Execute in the loop, the page goes to the internal server error page. And the database didn't update. I don't know too much about asp and vbscript. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: VB.NET has nothing to do with this question. It is just vbscript. (And I suppose that also ASP.NET is not correct instead use ASP-CLASSIC) Please don't add irrelevant and misleading tags

Comment: You create 2 parameters but call `objCmd.Parameters.Append( objParam )`only once.

Comment: Thanks Rubik, you're right.